# What is a clean way of maintaining the hashtag value when links are clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are no external links on my site, so I was thinking of selecting all the anchor tags: `$('a')` and appending the current hashtag value to the href of all of these, but this seems like a messy aproach. Is there a better way to do this? The url of my site looks like this: `www.rsadler.com/html/home.html#chairsAndTables` But when you click on any of my links, the url updates, obviously, without the hashtag.
 Thanks!

Comment: if this is information you need that should persist for a user's session, you might be better off using session cookies.

Comment: Do you mean "selecting all the anchor tags: $('.a')" or "selecting all the anchor tags: $('a')"?

Comment: @poopnoodles you are totally right!

Comment: You could just delegate the click event of all anchor tags, `$(document).on("click","a",function(){ this.href += location.hash;});` though this information would be better persisted through either cookies, session, or local storage.

Comment: This is the wrong approach, hashes should not be used to transfer information from one page to another. You should be using querystrings or local storage or something instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP actually meant the pages change but the hash need to carry forward to each subsequent page.

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var href=this.href.split('#')[0];
    $(this).attr('href', href + window.location.hash);
});
```

Comment: I still want my links to function normally though.

Comment: Define "function normally"

Comment: Go to where they say to go.

Comment: Wait do you mean `home.html#chairsAndTables` and `somepage.html#chairsAndTables` and `anotherpage.html#chairsAndTables` are all to carry the hash through?

Comment: @popnoodles: might want to strip off any existing hash before appending.

Comment: oh bugger i forgot that. impossible to put this in jsfiddle !

Comment: updated answer. if i need to edit this again i'm scrapping it!

Comment: You are the best poopnoodles! Love You!

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function(){ this.src += window.location.hash; });
});
```

Method 2: Session Cookie

```
window.onload = function() { 
    var winHash = window.location.hash;
    var cookieHash = unescape((document.cookie.match(new RegExp('\bhash=(.*?)(?:;|$)','i')) || [null,''])[1]);
    if(winHash == "" && cookieHash.length > 0)
        window.location.hash = cookieHash;
    else if(winHash != "")
        document.cookie = "hash=" + escape(winHash) + "; path=/";
}
```

**note** I didn't test the above JavaScript, so there may be syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on the event inside a click event handler for the links will prevent the browser updating the current URL.

Comment: I still want my links to function normally though.